# How to dynamically edit a excel vba form label and tab label?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel vba form which has some tabs(pages).What I need is, if I double click on label, it should be editable. same is the case for the tabs.
I tried to add some things into the double click function, but not showing any change.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried so far? Some indication of how your form would look like before and after the click event would also help!

Comment: You should really give us something more than that if you expect an answer, is the Label on a Userform? Images speak a thousand words... Help us help you...

Answer (score 0):

Labels are not editable by the end user

you may adopt this workaround

```
'change "Label1" occurrences to your actual label name
Private Sub Label1_DblClick()
    Me.Label1.Caption = Application.InputBox("enter label text", "label editing", "")
End Sub
```

Comment: @qwww, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `TextBox` and disable it. The side effect is you will have textbox edit cursor over the label.

Have two subroutines, one called `Labelize` and another `Textboxize`. The former locks the textbox, makes it tranparent, and sets the 3D effect to flat. The latter unlocks it, makes it opaque, and sets the 3D to sunken (the default).

```
' Makes a textbox look like a label
Private Sub Labelize(txtbox As MSForms.TextBox)
    txtbox.Locked = True
    txtbox.BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
    txtbox.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
End Sub

' Makes a textbox look like a textbox
Private Sub Textboxize(txtbox As MSForms.TextBox)

    txtbox.Locked = False
    txtbox.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
    txtbox.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
End Sub
```

In the form initialize event set call the `Labelize` method passing in your textboxes.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Labelize Me.txtExample
End Sub
```

In the double-click event per textbox, call the `Textboxize` method passing in your textbox again.

```
Private Sub txtExample_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Textboxize Me.txtExample
End Sub
```

Then in each `KeyDown` event, check if the key pressed was enter then call the `Labelize` method.

```
Private Sub txtExample_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then Labelize Me.txtExample
End Sub
```